# Xcode Capabilities check

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase, applepay

First I am letting you know that this not the question about Xcode capabilities ON|OFF, Its about get capabilities dynamically.

As per below image, I have enabled In-App Purchase but Apple pay is disabled for the movement.

[image]

I want to check using coding(Swift|Objective-C) if apple pay capability enabled or not ? same for the In-App purchase.

Thanks for reading this.